# HDF5 Rescale Dataset Maximum Dimension

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have created a Data Set with chunking layout, I have determined the maximum size of the dataset

```
DataSpace *dataspace = new DataSpace (2, dims, maxdims)//maxdims equal to dims
// Modify dataset creation property to enable chunking
DSetCreatPropList prop;
prop.setChunk(2, chunk_dims);
```

Then I recorded some data in it. Lately I was in need to resize this dataset but the new size exceed maximum size I determined in the begining which cause an exception each time I try to resize dataset

```
dataset->extend(new_size); //New size
```

Is there a way I can Extend the maximum dimension of data set without losing my recorded data. If not is there a way to overwrite the dataset by an another one contains my data and with the new max size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option ::extend() is only available to extendible datasets ([link](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.intro.html#Intro-PMCreateExtendible)).

If your dataset was created with a maximum size, you can't change it to an extendible one. You have to copy the contents to a new dataset created as unlimited.

Here you have an example taken from the hdf website ([link](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/extend_ds_8cpp-example.html)).

```
/*
 *   This example shows how to work with extendible dataset.
 *   In the current version of the library dataset MUST be
 *   chunked.
 */
#ifdef OLD_HEADER_FILENAME
#include <iostream.h>
#else
#include <iostream>
#endif
#include <string>
#ifndef H5_NO_NAMESPACE
#ifndef H5_NO_STD
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
#endif  // H5_NO_STD
#endif
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#ifndef H5_NO_NAMESPACE
    using namespace H5;
#endif
const H5std_string FILE_NAME( "SDSextendible.h5" );
const H5std_string DATASET_NAME( "ExtendibleArray" );
const int      NX = 10;
const int      NY = 5;
const int      RANK = 2;
int main (void)
{
   //Try block to detect exceptions raised by any of the calls inside it
   try
   {
      /*
       * Turn off the auto-printing when failure occurs so that we can
       * handle the errors appropriately
       */
      Exception::dontPrint();

      //Create the data space with unlimited dimensions.
      hsize_t      dims[2]  = { 3, 3};  // dataset dimensions at creation
      hsize_t      maxdims[2] = {H5S_UNLIMITED, H5S_UNLIMITED};
      DataSpace mspace1( RANK, dims, maxdims);

      //Create a new file. If file exists its contents will be overwritten.
      H5File file( FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_TRUNC );

      //Modify dataset creation properties, i.e. enable chunking.          
      DSetCreatPropList cparms;
      hsize_t      chunk_dims[2] ={2, 5};
      cparms.setChunk( RANK, chunk_dims );

      //Set fill value for the dataset          
      int fill_val = 0;
      cparms.setFillValue( PredType::NATIVE_INT, &fill_val);

      //Create a new dataset within the file using cparms creation properties.
      DataSet dataset = file.createDataSet( DATASET_NAME, PredType::NATIVE_INT, mspace1, cparms);

      //Extend the dataset. This call assures that dataset is at least 3 x 3.
      hsize_t      size[2];
      size[0]   = 3;
      size[1]   = 3;
      dataset.extend( size );

      //Select a hyperslab.
      DataSpace fspace1 = dataset.getSpace ();
      hsize_t     offset[2];
      offset[0] = 0;
      offset[1] = 0;
      hsize_t      dims1[2] = { 3, 3};            /* data1 dimensions */
      fspace1.selectHyperslab( H5S_SELECT_SET, dims1, offset );

      //Write the data to the hyperslab.          
      int       data1[3][3] = { {1, 1, 1},       /* data to write */
                {1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1} };
      dataset.write( data1, PredType::NATIVE_INT, mspace1, fspace1 );

      //Extend the dataset. Dataset becomes 10 x 3.           
      hsize_t   dims2[2] = { 7, 1};            /* data2 dimensions */
      dims[0]   = dims1[0] + dims2[0];
      size[0]   = dims[0];
      size[1]   = dims[1];
      dataset.extend( size );

      //Select a hyperslab.         
      DataSpace fspace2 = dataset.getSpace ();
      offset[0] = 3;
      offset[1] = 0;
      fspace2.selectHyperslab( H5S_SELECT_SET, dims2, offset );

      //Define memory space
      DataSpace mspace2( RANK, dims2 );

      //Write the data to the hyperslab.
      int  data2[7]    = { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
      dataset.write( data2, PredType::NATIVE_INT, mspace2, fspace2 );

      //Extend the dataset. Dataset becomes 10 x 5.
      hsize_t   dims3[2] = { 2, 2};            /* data3 dimensions */
      dims[1]   = dims1[1] + dims3[1];
      size[0]   = dims[0];
      size[1]   = dims[1];
      dataset.extend( size );

      //Select a hyperslab          
      DataSpace fspace3 = dataset.getSpace ();
      offset[0] = 0;
      offset[1] = 3;
      fspace3.selectHyperslab( H5S_SELECT_SET, dims3, offset );

      //Define memory space.
      DataSpace mspace3( RANK, dims3 );

      //Write the data to the hyperslab.          
      int         data3[2][2] = { {3, 3}, {3, 3} };
      dataset.write( data3, PredType::NATIVE_INT, mspace3, fspace3 );

      //Read the data from this dataset and display it.          
      int i, j;
      int data_out[NX][NY];
      for (i = 0; i < NX; i++)
      {
         for (j = 0; j < NY; j++)
            data_out[i][j] = 0;
      }
      dataset.read( data_out, PredType::NATIVE_INT );
      /*
       * Resulting dataset
       *
       *     1 1 1 3 3
       *     1 1 1 3 3
       *     1 1 1 0 0
       *     2 0 0 0 0
       *     2 0 0 0 0
       *     2 0 0 0 0
       *     2 0 0 0 0
       *     2 0 0 0 0
       *     2 0 0 0 0
       *     2 0 0 0 0
       */

      //Display the result.          
      for (i=0; i < NX; i++)
      {
          for(j=0; j < NY; j++)
             cout << data_out[i][j] << "  ";
          cout << endl;
      }
   }  // end of try block
   // catch failure caused by the H5File operations
   catch( FileIException error )
   {
      error.printError();
      return -1;
   }
   // catch failure caused by the DataSet operations
   catch( DataSetIException error )
   {
      error.printError();
      return -1;
   }
   // catch failure caused by the DataSpace operations
   catch( DataSpaceIException error )
   {
      error.printError();
      return -1;
   }
   // catch failure caused by the DataSpace operations
   catch( DataTypeIException error )
   {
      error.printError();
      return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I understand that I can put the maximum Dataset size unlimited, my question what if I have recorded data with a maximum size limited and I need to resize it to exceed this limit what shall I do?

Comment: If I were you I would create a new file and copy the data to a new dataset with unlimited dimensions.  However, if you want to use the same file, you can create a new dataset (unlimited), copy the data from the fixed dataset, delete the fixed dataset, and if you want, rename the unlimited dataset to have the name of the deleted dataset.

Comment: You can only extend a dataset if it was created with the unlimited dimensions option. You can't do it after.

Comment: You must probably right about that, is the resizing possible if that data saved in a contiguous manner?

Comment: As far as I know ([link](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.intro.html#Intro-PMCreateExtendible)) a dataset can only be extended if its dataspace was created as "unlimited", and that option is only available for chunked storage layouts

Comment: One last question what's the difference(code wise) between defining a dataset as contiguous or as chunking layout? How can I convert your data set to contiguous dataset....also please edit your answer so I can count it right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141411/discussion-between-miral-and-pablo-worker).